# Does setting the buffertimeout setting in Flink to 0 ms impact preformace?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been doing some testing with latency and throughput in Flink. I am measuring the average latency and throughput of records in my Flink cluster. I was looking into the Buffer timeout configuration. I noticed that Flink recommends avoiding a timeout of 0 ms; however, I noticed no severe performance degradation even with large message loads. What is the downside to lowering this value to zero? I understand it may be aggressive, but I am genuinely curious to the impacts this setting has on performance. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old, but I'm not aware of any more recent benchmarking, and I think the results shown here for Flink 1.5 should still be reasonably indicative of what you can expect. Which is that a buffer timeout of 1 ms is probably a better choice in most cases where latency is important, but not super critical, but choosing 0 is not impossibly painful.

[image: Effect of buffer timeout on throughput]